# Adding the captions via the google drive sdk

Tags: google-drive-api

I have 1k+ closed captions (in the srt format) and I would like to add all of them to my videos on the google drive. Is it possible to do it via the API?

thank you
Radek

Comment: Do you need to load the closed caption when you load the videos via drive?

Comment: yes, in other words I'm looking something similar to https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions
Thank you

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is possible through [Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk). See [Upload Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads). You have three choices for this, Simple upload, Multipart upload and Resumable upload.

> **Simple upload**
>
> The most straightforward method for uploading a file is by making a simple upload request. This option is a good choice when:
>
> - The file is small enough to upload again in its entirety if the connection fails.
> - There is no metadata to send. This might be true if you plan to send metadata for this resource in a separate request, or if no metadata is supported or available.
>
> **Multipart upload**
>
> If you have metadata that you want to send along with the data to upload, you can make a single multipart/related request. This is a good choice if the data you are sending is small enough to upload again in its entirety if the connection fails.
>
> **Resumable upload**
>
> To upload data files more reliably, you can use the resumable upload protocol. This protocol allows you to resume an upload operation after a communication failure has interrupted the flow of data. It is especially useful if you are transferring large files and the likelihood of a network interruption or some other transmission failure is high, for example, when uploading from a mobile client app. It can also reduce your bandwidth usage in the event of network failures because you don't have to restart large file uploads from the beginning.

You may also want to see [Work with Folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder) for inserting files in a folder.