# Access WebVTT subtitle from Google Drive in HTML 5 video tag

Tags: javascript, html, google-drive-api, html5-video

I am by no means a web developer so forgive me if I am missing something blindly obvious. I have checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880756/stream-video-from-google-drive-in-html-5-video-tag) and I found out that it's work fine with .mp4 file but WebVTT file (.vtt) was not usable. [I think the player recognized the subtile as the player bar show "CC" button but in the video, subtitle was not displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xjyk.png) Did I do something wrong? Any help would be appriciated.

Here is my JS code. The subtitle track file work fine when I am using local file on my computer but when I am using drv the same like the .mp4 file, it was not working anymore.

```
<script>
  function myFunction1() {
   document.getElementById("myVideo").src= "https://www-drv.com/~email/gd/Testing/NG!-01.mp4";
   document.getElementById("mySubtitle").src= "https://www-drv.com/~email/gd/Testing/01.vtt";
   document.querySelector('video').load();
  }
</script>
```

And here is my video code

```
<video width="1280" height="720" controls="controls" preload="none">
  <source id="myVideo" src="https://www-drv.com/~email/gd/Testing/NG!-01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <track id="mySubtitle" src="https://www-drv.com/~email/gd/Testing/01.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="id" label="English" default>
</video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out the solution. The track won't work because the subtitle hosting server was not enabled CORS.
Just need to add this to the .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
     Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/1372218?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) is maybe the reason why it is not working.

> Prepare your caption file Although you can upload captions in any
>   format, only **SubRip (*.SRT) and SubViewer (*.SUB) are supported**.
>
> To help with readability:
>
> - To help people with hearing disabilities, put descriptions like [music] or [laughter] inside square brackets.
> - To show when the speaker changes, add >> at the beginning of a new line.
>
> You can find software to help you create these files or hire a company
>   to make them for you. [Learn how to create a caption and transcript
>   files](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/100076).

You may also check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35010700/adding-the-captions-via-the-google-drive-sdk) for further reference.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I don't think this relevant to what I am doing at all. Basically, I am using HTML5 video tag to play video and subtitle but my problem is the code works fine with the local URL but after uploaded to Google Drive, the code only work with the .mp4 URL and not the .vtt URL.